# How to replace parentheses with all the content inside?

Tags: dart

I have string as shown below. My question is: How to replace parentheses with all the content inside in Dart?

Example-1:

- Original: String _myText = "Netflix.com(Amsterdam)";
- Expected Text: "Netflix.com"

Example-2:

- Original: String _myText = "The dog has a long(brown) tail.";
- Expected Text: "The dog has a long tail."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp:

```
void main() {
  String _myText1 = "Netflix.com(Amsterdam)";
  print(_myText1.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\(.*\)'), '')); // Netflix.com

  String _myText2 = "The dog has a long(brown) tail.";
  print(_myText2.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\(.*\)'), '')); // The dog has a long tail.
}
```